# Java - How to Auth Username and Password

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How to authenticate email's(Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail and AOL) username and password?
Where should put the cide to auth email?

This is my code

```
public class AuthMail
{
    public static void authEmail()
    {
        if(LoginDialog.t_Email.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            Util.printErrorMessage("Plase Enter an Email Address");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Plase Enter an Email Address", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if(LoginDialog.p_Password.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Plase Enter Your Password");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Plase Enter Your Password", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if(Util.getMailType().equals("GMail"))
        {
            System.out.println("Logging...");
            System.out.println("Attempting connection to GMail...");
        }
        else if(Util.getMailType().equals("Yahoo"))
        {
           System.out.println("Logging...");
            System.out.println("Attempting connection to Yahoo...");
        }
        else if(Util.getMailType().equals("Yahoo"))
        {
            System.out.println("Logging...");
            System.out.println("Attempting connection to Hotmail...");
        }
        else if(Util.getMailType().equals("AOL"))
        {
            System.out.println("Logging...");
            System.out.println("Attempting connection to Aol...");
        }
        else if(Util.getMailType().equals("Unknown"))
        {
            System.out.println("Mail Type Unknown");
            int var1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Email Type Unknown. Did you want to try again?", "Error", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(var1 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

NOTE : Util.class is created by myself.

Comment: Well for one thing, you need JInputDialog boxes instead of JMessageDialog for requesting input.

Comment: @lonnez No. I use JFrame with JPanel with JTextField and JPasswordField

Comment: you basically want to check if user has entered correct set of username and password.

Comment: @ SuKu Yes i only want to check whether user has entered correct username and password or not

Comment: @KenWong Oh I see what you are doing now. I thought that was where you were asking them to input it. I didn't think too far into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Store.connect method that takes a host, user, and password.  You're collecting the username and password.  The host name will be different in each branch of your "if".  You'll find host names for common services in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Comment: what will the connect() method return if it fail to connect?

Comment: AS described in the [javadocs](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Service.html#connect(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), connect returns void, but throws exceptions such as AuthenticationFailedException to indicate authentication problems and MessagingException to indicate other problems (such as problems connecting).